What can I do to improve my questions that my questions will be accepted again (regrettably I have got the question ban)?
I don't know what to do. The question ban has come all of a sudden - there was no warning or admonishment. When I look at my questions there is hardly any possibility to fix them. The last 6 questions were all answered and one was closed with the note it could be answered using a dictionary. So there isn't any possibility to improve these questions and there isn't any possibility to regain new acceptance. I don't know what to do.

As it says in the MSE FAQ I previously linked for you:

To help prevent you from encountering a ban, the system will give you
a warning if you are on the road to a ban, and may temporarily prevent
you from posting questions or answers for a few days. If, despite these
warnings and rate limits, you continue to post too many poorly-received
questions or answers, you will be altogether banned from posting more,
and you will see the error message.

You posted after being presented with a quality ban warning three times within the past month:

2024-05-26 14:58:52Z
2024-06-07 16:02:01Z
2024-06-08 10:43:24Z

That same linked FAQ further explains:

Are deleted posts taken into account too?
If a post was poorly received (downvoted or closed), those negative
marks will continue to count against your account even if the post is
deleted! Whenever possible, try to fix posts instead of deleting them.
Additionally, for question bans, the fact that a question
is deleted counts against you, if others have invested
time into answering or moderating the question. (This
does not apply to questions that are 30 days or older when
deleted,
though any negative marks on those questions can still count against you.)

At the bottom of your questions
page,
you should see a link to your own Deleted
questions.
Except for those which were migrated away and therefore locked, you
should be able to edit the deleted ones to improve them.  Then you should
undelete them so that the community members can see those improvements
and with luck upvote them if those improvements merit this.
If for any reason you cannot do that for the questions that
are not locked following migration, you should flag that
question for moderator attention and explain the difficulty.

Thank you. - "If for any reason you cannot do that for the questions that are not locked following migration" - I don't understand that: 1) Do you mean the closed questions are locked and that's why I can't fix them? 2) Does that mean I have to improve the migrated questions as well? I can't imagine I have to improve questions that were answered on SE ELL. (It's a very tricky and intricate jungle - these procedures of up-and downvoting and their consequences. You should think it over to quit the whole thing, actually.. It sucks)

I've read it once again. Now I understand "If for any reason you cannot do that for the questions that are not locked following migration" to mean I am to improve all those questions that aren't locked. Questions that have been migrated are locked owing to the migration. and I cannot improve them.
